# Show UIButton when Image is touched?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uibutton

is there any way to hide an UIButton until the UIImageView is pressed??
When the picture is pressed I need to show the back Button, like it works at the Photo App on the iPhone???
Here is the code of my UIButton:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self ladeImage];
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 40, 40);
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(goToViewA) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn setTitle:@"<<" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];

    }
```

Comment: Is there a way for you to accept more answers to the 24 questions you have asked?

Comment: What is your problem? sorry i can't understand what you mean

Comment: There is an option on the website to say if an answer is the good one or not. And you didn't accept any answer on (all) your questions. So maybe you could begin by this step

Comment: Please say what i have to do and i will do it :)

Comment: Did you mean, to check hoe under the 0??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step : `btn.hidden = YES`

Then you have to subclass the UIImageView to react to its `touchesEnded:` event and change the hidden property of your button there.  For that, the proper way is to create a protocol (with a viewTouched method).  Implement that protocol in the viewController containing your button and you ImageView. Add a delegate propery to the subclassed ImageView (i.e. `id<MyCustomProtocol> _delagate;`) and assign the view controller to this propery.

Comment: Ok i have solved the Problem now it works, thank you a lot and I have accept the answer too :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.hidden = YES;

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image name"]];
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; // here to enable touch event
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGestureRecongizer:)]; // handleTapGestureRecongizer is method will call when tap even fire
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap]; // Add Tap gesture recognizer to image view
[tap release], tap = nil;
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release], imageView = nil;
```

Method handlerTapGestureRecognizer:

```
- (void)handleTapGestureRecongizer:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    btn.hidden = NO;
}
```

}

have fun!